# Mysql insert only if conditions are met

Tags: mysql

Ok what I want to do is this.
I only want to insert if the amount I am inserting, plus the sum of the column is not over my value eg 112. I am only summing one invoice amount which is where the sales invoice id comes in. So I am going to add an amount of £20.

So I basically need a query which says
Insert Amount if Amount+"Sum of column" is smaller than or equal to the total quantity.

So here is my table layout

```
sipID|SalesInvoice_id|Date|Amount
1|116|07/11/2017|2|
2|115|07/11/2017|88|
3|116|07/11/2017|22|
7|115|07/11/2017|22|
```

So I thought an INSERT SELECT might work so I started getting the SELECT query to work first, and here is my working select query

```
SELECT SUM(`Amount`) FROM `salesinvoice_payments`
GROUP BY `SalesInvoice_id` HAVING SUM(`Amount`)+20 <= 112 AND `SalesInvoice_id`=115
```

Basically at the moment I am hard coding the amount I wish to add which is 20.
So what this select statement is doing. It will only get a value if the SUM(`Amount`)+20 is smaller or equal to 112 which is my total.
This works nicely.

So back to my original question. I want to insert only if the condition is true.
I can't seem to get the right format for this to work eg

```
INSERT INTO `salesinvoice_payments` (`Amount`)VALUES (20)
SELECT SUM(`Amount`) FROM `salesinvoice_payments`
GROUP BY `SalesInvoice_id` HAVING SUM(`Amount`)+20 <= 100 AND `SalesInvoice_id`=115
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is without the `VALUES` statement.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Yes but the select is being used like a where clause. I want to insert the value 20 if the condition is met. I am not sure how to lay it out, but I have put what I have worked out so far. I know the query I have put is wrong, but I don't know how to put it right.

Comment: i've posted a answer what should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is without the `VALUES` statement.

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO `salesinvoice_payments` (`Amount`)
SELECT 20 FROM `salesinvoice_payments`
GROUP BY `SalesInvoice_id` HAVING SUM(`Amount`) + 20 <= 100 AND `SalesInvoice_id`= 115
```

Comment: I didn't think of putting the value in the select statement. Thanks. I was so close as well.